# Cumulatively Reduce Values in Column by Results of Another Column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, loops, iteration

I am dealing with a dataset that shows duplicate stock per part and location.  Orders from multiple customers are coming in and the stock was just added via a vlookup.  I need help writing some sort of looping function in python that cumulatively decreases the stock quantity by the order quantity.

Currently data looks like this:

```
    SKU     Plant   Order  Stock
0   5455    989     2      90
1   5455    989     15     90
2   5455    990     10     80
3   5455    990     20     80
```

I want to accomplish this:

```
    SKU     Plant   Order   Stock
0   5455    989     2       88
1   5455    989     15      73
2   5455    990     10      70
3   5455    990     20      50
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
df.Stock -= df.groupby(['SKU','Plant'])['Order'].cumsum()
```